# Plotly axis labels on multiple lines alignment

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm building a Shiny application with some Plotly horizontal bar charts. Some data labels are pretty long and I want to break them on multiple lines. It works when places `<br>` on the place I want to break the line, but alignment of the axis labels does not go well. See picture below of output (left) and desired plot (right).

[image: Plotly output (left) and desired output (right)]

Below a minimal working example. It left out the Shiny part, because I expect that this does not affect the possible solution.

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = paste0('This is a pretty long sentence',1:10),
  dimA = 1:10
)

df$name <- gsub('This is a pretty long sentence','This is a<br>pretty long<br>sentence',df$name)


## Hide axes
ax <- list(
  title = "",
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  domain = list(0.2, 1)
)
ay <- list(
  title = "",
  zeroline = FALSE,
  showline = FALSE,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE
)

p <- df %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~dimA, 
          y = ~name,
          type = 'bar',
          orientation = 'h'
  ) %>%
  layout(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ay)
p
```

Help is highly appreciated! Struggling with this for hours, but unable to find a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very general but you can adjust the tick position using tickvals, for example:

```
ay <- list(
title = "",
zeroline = FALSE,
showline = FALSE,
showticklabels = TRUE,
showgrid = FALSE, 
tickvals = 0:9 + 0.25
)
```

Comment: Works fine for the problem above! You can of course dynamically build a wrapper around it, counting the number of breaks and constructing the tickvalues dynamically. Thx KGee for pointing in the right direction.